# How to reply to the message in OMNet++

Tags: omnet++

Is there a simple way to reply to the node from which I've got the message? 
I.e. I have a net of nodes which have multiple inputs and outputs, and linked to each other. I get a message from some node in handleMessage(), I can even get the gate id from which I got the message to my node. But how do I find which of my outs is connected to this node, from which I got the message, so that I could reply like:

```
send(reply, "out", senderId);
```

I've come to solution like this, but it feels overcomplicated:

```
cGate * sender = msg->getSenderGate();
for (cModule::GateIterator i(this); !i.end(); i++)
{
     cGate *gate = i();
     std::string gateStr = gate->getName();
     if (gateStr == "out" && gate->getPathEndGate()->getOwnerModule() == sender->getOwnerModule() )
     {
         int senderId = gate->getIndex();
         send(reply, "out", senderId); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `inout` gates? If so, this could be as simple as:

```
gateHalf(msg->getArrivalGate()->getName(), cGate::OUTPUT)
```

Comment: unfortunately sometimes it crashes with messages like: No such gate or gate vector: '' -- in module (Txc10) Tictoc10.Hub1 (id=2), at t=0s, event #3
Even though I have all the in/out links set up properly. So I have to stick to my own solution